# Change the specific text become a number in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

Can I actually Make a specific text become a number in Excel? For example, in Column B:B there are a lot of A and B, and I want to change A=1 and B=2. If this is not clear, take a look the picture :

This is the first data :

[image]

And this is my expectation :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Create a lookup table like this (can be in the same sheet or another sheet, I put it in cells `A1:B2` of `Sheet2`):

```
+---+---+
| A | 1 |
+---+---+
| B | 2 |
+---+---+
```

2) In the column next to the letters, use the following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!A41:B$2,2)
```

And populate down

Answer (score 2):

One option you could consider, in addition to Nomad's response:

Add a helper column in cell C2 with an IF/ELSE formula:

```
=IF($B2=1,"A",IF($B2=2,"B","other"))
```

And populate down